Index out of range error from code to extract data from API
So I'm trying to extract data from an API but I keep getting an error saying the list is out of range. I'm fairly new to Python so I understand what the problem is but not sure how I can edit the code to run. If you can please help with the below code, it would help a lot. Thank you!
z = 11

names = []  
charge_types = []  
addresss = []  
latitudes = [] 
longitudes = []  
states = []  
outputs = []  
methods = []  
zcodes = []  
limityns = []  
limitdetails = []  
parking_frees = []  

page_num = 1
while 1:
    response = (url + 'ServiceKey=' + ServiceKey + '&numOfRows=1000' + '&pageNo='+ str(page_num)    +'&zcode=' + str(z))
    url_new = response.encode('utf-8')
    req = requests.get(url_new)
    bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

    name = bs.findAll('statnm')
    charge_type = bs.findAll('chgertype')
    address = bs.findAll('addr')
    latitude = bs.findAll('lat')
    longitude = bs.findAll('lng')
    state = bs.findAll('stat')
    output = bs.findAll('output')
    method = bs.findAll('method')
    zcode = bs.findAll('zcode')
    limityn = bs.findAll('limitYn')
    limitdetail = bs.findAll('limitDetail')
    parking_free = bs.findAll('parkingfree')

    total_num = str(bs.find('totalcount'))
    total = int(re.findall('d+', total_num)[0])

    if page_num < total // 1000 + 1:
        for i in range(1000):
            names.append(name[i].text)
            charge_types.append(charge_type[i].text)
            addresss.append(address[i].text)
            latitudes.append(latitude[i].text)
            longitudes.append(longitude[i].text)
            states.append(state[i].text)
            outputs.append(output[i].text)
            methods.append(method[i].text)
            zcodes.append(zcode[i].text)
            try:
                limityns.append(limityn[i].text)
                limitdetails.append(limitdetail[i].text)
            except:
                limityns.append('')
                limitdetails.append('')
            parking_frees.append(parking_free[i].text)
        
        page_num += 1

    else:
        for i in range(total%1000):
            names.append(name[i].text)
            charge_types.append(charge_type[i].text)
            addresss.append(address[i].text)
            latitudes.append(latitude[i].text)
            longitudes.append(longitude[i].text)
            states.append(state[i].text)
            outputs.append(output[i].text)
            methods.append(method[i].text)
            zcodes.append(zcode[i].text)
            try:
                limityns.append(limityn[i].text)
                limitdetails.append(limitdetail[i].text)
            except:
                limityns.append('')
                limitdetails.append('')
            parking_frees.append(parking_free[i].text)
        
        break

Error message I'm getting:
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 41 total = int(re.findall('d+', total_num)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range


re.findall('d+', total_num) is [] so if you do re.findall('d+', total_num)[0] you will get : IndexError: list index out of range.

`basicly it means that re.findall('d+', total_num) is empty, meaning it didn't find any digits in the string total_num. Can u share your total_num output before using regex. So, we can try to find solution.

There is an typo error in your regex. I think you mean re.findall(r'\d+', total_num)[0] - note the backslash before d.  Alternatively you could use total = re.search(r"(\d+)", total_num).group(). Note that if these do NOT find digits then a NoneType will be returned and this causes an Error if you try and cast to an Int.
